# How to browse when click other button

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to simulate the browse button, so when you click other button let it browse the file input?

Comment: Please be more specific. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really easy just make it

```
<a href="#" onclick="form.browse.click();return false;">Browse</a>
```